# Process Builder - Does it have a way to activate from metadata or something?

Tags: process-builder

I want to know Process Builder has way to activate(not from salesforce site) like a ant tool or something else.

Comment: Welcome to sfse, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include details of your problem (screenshots, steps to reproduce etc.) alongside with any errors you get when applied your solution.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on your use case a bit more? The answers above are good, but I am not sure if either of them answers your question or if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform activations and deactivations using a Metadata API tool such as Workbench, as Naval explains in another answer. I wanted to point to another approach that does not require performing a deployment.

In your Criteria nodes in Process Builder, you can reference values from the `$Setup` domain, which allows you to pull in values from your Hierarchy Custom Settings. You can define Custom Settings fields that enable or disable all Processes or specific Processes, and then use references to these fields in your Process Builder criteria to prevent criteria from evaluating to `true` and executing actions.

Here's an example showing a reference to a `Run__c` checkbox on an `Instance_Settings__c` Custom Setting:

[image: Process Builder screenshot]

This approach can give you very fine-grained control over your Processes, if you apply it pervasively, and you can control it simply by changing Custom Settings records in your user interface or via the API/Data Loader. No Metadata API needed.

It's a very different approach from using deployments, and each has a place depending on your specific needs.

Comment: David, It depends on the use-case. if the OP wanted to delete the flow, or activate other versions (using CI, for example) the above sample won't cut it. Good idea, tho, I will def use it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workbench to activate/deactivate a process builder.

You just need to download the metadata using the Workbench's UI and then modify the flowDefinition file with the version you want to activate. After making the changes deploy that file again using the Workbench.

[**LINK TO THE ARTICLE**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221117&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=1)